"Is 'Atimaharathi' a fake term? If not, what is its reference in ancient texts like the Vedas, Puranas, or Itihasas?
"Is 'Atimaharathi' a   Newly created fake term? If not, what is its reference in ancient texts like the Vedas, Puranas, or Itihasas?
Please provide exact refrence.
